# ReferenceError: $ is not defined on jquery.are-you-sure.js

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am a beginner  in **jquery** 
I have test.aspx page :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery.are-you-sure.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(function () {
            $('form').areYouSure();
            $('form').areYouSure({ 'message': 'Your profile details are not saved!' });
     });
        </script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <!DOCTYPE html>

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I get error:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined (Line #5)

I am tired to find the  solution.

Comment: JQuery file is not loading

Comment: Most likely the specified .js files are not in the location you indicated. You need to provide the correct path to them. And for goodness' sake, the `<script>` elements should be inside the `<head>` or `<body>` element and the `<!DOCTYPE html>` should be at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggesting that you don't have `jquery-1.8.2.min` file at the same label where your page is.

Like suppose you have file `test.aspx` on root folder then your script file should on root.

And if you script file is inside a folder then you need to specify the folder name

```
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="yourFolder/jquery-1.8.2.min"></script>
```

Comment: thanks .. i missing file name

Answer (score 0):

I update the code, I was missing folder name.
jquery.are-you-sure.js plugin run correctly now

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script  type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.are-you-sure.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function () {
            $('form').areYouSure();
            $('form').areYouSure({ 'message': 'Your profile details are not saved!' });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is still a complete mess. Did you read my comment?

Comment: yes JLRishe i read your comments ..my code run correctly .. i get from web console "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead."

Comment: Sounds like that library is using outdated APIs. But that's a separate matter. Even if your code runs correctly, you should still fix your HTML. It's all messed up.

Comment: @JLRishe yes thanks..